# Adding null=True , blank=True in custom model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using custom modelfield for language. The snippet is shown -

```
from django.conf import settings

class LanguageField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 5)
        kwargs.setdefault('choices', settings.LANGUAGES)

        super(LanguageField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "CharField"
```

I want to allow null values for language. So, I know one thing that i have to append ((None,"None"),) to choices to display none as option in dropdown. But what how to set null=True and blank=True for this field.

```
language=LanguageField(null=True,blank=True)
```

doesnot works.It gives error `Column 'language' cannot be null`

Comment: There is nothing special about doing this for a customv field. Did you create and run migrations?

Comment: true ! silly mistake i did :(